# after dismissing View one subview hast different place

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, presentviewcontroller

Hello I have a problem with un/showing a `TableViewController`.

I have a `Scrollview` with 4Subviews (the last `subView` is optionally, if a Button is clicked or not).
In this optionally subview is a Button. If the button is clicked a new View with a TableView will open. If i click a cell in this TableView i want to go back to the last View.

Everything works fine, but the optionally `View` is shown always in the middle of the Screen instead of the last `View` on the `ScrollView`.

function to show the TableView:

```
- (void)CategoryButtonClicked:(id)sender {
[self presentViewController:advancedSearchTableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
advancedSearchTableViewController.SourceView = @"Category";}
```

function to dismiss the Table View:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Container View** pattern and add your tableViewController as a child view controller.
Here is a good reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html